# convert a datagrid column to Hyperlink

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

In my application, there is a data grid which is being populated by a feature service.

Using the following code in the ViewModel, it achieves the visiblity toggle feature of a hard coded column.

```
_featureDataGridService.FeatureDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

//* to show the  object id column for specific layers of a service

if (_configService.ProjectConfiguration.ProjectTitle == "Customer profile")
{

    if (SelectedItem == "New Survey Areas")
    {
        _featureDataGridService.FeatureDataGrid.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
       //**above line of code shows the object id column of the datagrid
    }
    else
    {
        _featureDataGridService.FeatureDataGrid.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;                      

    }
}
```

Here is the related XAML code:
Below is my whole datagrid code:

```
<slData:DataGrid x:Name="CustomerDetailsDataGrid"   
ItemsSource=" {Binding     SingleReturnedItemAttributes}"  
AutoGenerateColumns="False"HeadersVisibility="None"   
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" MaxHeight="350"   
MaxWidth="350">

<slData:DataGrid.Columns>
 <slData:DataGridTextColumn    Binding="  {Binding Path=Key}" 
  FontWeight="Bold"/>
 <slData:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Visibility="
{Binding Path=Value,Converter={StaticResource theHttpVisbilityConverter}}" 
 />
 <slData:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Visibility="
 {Binding Path=Value,Converter={StaticResource theHttpVisbilityConverter}, 
 ConverterParameter=reverse}" />
</slData:DataGrid.Columns>
```

---

So now my data grid has new service that has a column called `Custmer_url` which contains the full url of customer specific pdf docs.

I need to make the column clickable(hyperlink).

The datagrid needs to be autogenerated as the grid is used by other services as well and hence I can not hardcode the column as template in the XAML. In this scenario how can I make the columns that contain `http://` to be hyperlink column dynamically .

Comment: Will you be having the column list(property names) that have hyperlinks ? or you want to make the column as hyperlink only when the values have http://.

Comment: I want the column as hyperlink when it has http://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make two controls in the column, where one has a hyperlink and one without. Then create a visibility converter to determine if the text needs a hyperlink.

If the converter detects HTTP it returns visible, if not return collapsed.

**Converter**

```
public class HTTPVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool boolVisbility  = (value != null) && value.ToString().StartsWith("http");

        boolVisbility = (parameter != null) ? !boolVisbility : boolVisbility;

        return boolVisbility ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

For example if we had two textboxes this is how the call would be done. Note we pass in a parameter text object as "reverse", you could pass in anything such as a number 1 for the same affect.

```
 <converters:HTTPVisibilityConverter x:Name="theHttpVisbilityConverter"/>

  ...

 <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}"
            Visibility="{Binding ., 
                         Converter={StaticResource theHttpVisbilityConverter}}" />

 <TextBlock Text="{Binding . }"
            Visibility="{Binding ., 
                         Converter={StaticResource theHttpVisbilityConverter},
                         ConverterParameter=Reverse}" />
```

Comment: Thank You Omega fan for your response. After implementing your idea like this <xData:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Visibility="{Binding Path=Value,Converter={StaticResource theHttpVisbilityConverter}}" /> i am getting an expection error for the Visibility value. Can you please let me know my wrong doing here

Comment: @ayaantara Update your question with the actual exception.

Comment: Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.Visibility'.  This what I get from the message.

Comment: @ayaantara You don't show a property named `Value` on you example being bound to but `OBJECTID`. Why the new item? Without the full code sample, I cannot determine what Value is and why it can't be bound.

Comment: Hi omega man , I have edited my xaml code in the original section. Please check . When I remove the Visibility part from  <slData:DataGridTextColumn  it works but does not when its present. Is my visibility part of the code correct

Comment: @OmegaMan how can you add converter to autogenerated columns?

Comment: @OmegaMan My application is an MVVM . How can i use the converter through ViewModel.cs.for the visibility property.